# VB6 SQL Selecting results based off results from another query

Tags: sql, vb6

I'm working on some VB6 code to connect to a database to return a specific subset of data. All the info needed is in the one table but I'm having a bit of trouble in establishing the correct approach to selecting my results based off of the results from another query.

Below is the SQL generated by Access when I created my queries there but I'm trying to convert them for use in my VB6 application:

'*EDIT --

```
" & Chr(34) & lstAb.Text & Chr(34) & "
```

The above thanks to David pushed steered this code in the right direction. From there, I used the debug window to confirm my selections in Access which was truly a magnificent experience. Had to tweak my aliases a bit but everything became very apparent when Access was asking me to key in other values that should've already been declared.

Thanks again to David!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be far better off doing some proper joins between the two tables, rather than specifying a sub-query.  However, that's not the problem, I don't think.

Looking at the code, I believe that you're missing some quotation marks around your criteria.  You say:

```
"...clone_id = " & lstAb.Text & ") ORDER..."
```

This should probably be:

```
"...clone_id = " & Chr(34) & lstAb.Text & Chr(34) & ") ORDER..."
```

to give you quotations around the text found in `lstAb.Text`.

An easy way to test these kind of functions is to `Debug.Print(sSql)` and look at the `Debug` window to see what the SQL is looking like.  Take a copy of that SQL, drop it into a new query in MSAccess (you can tell the query to "View SQL"), then try to figure out where it's going wrong.

This is much easier to see if your query doesn't have a nested query in it, as you can view the query designer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It has been a solid decade since I've worked with VB6 and much of it has escaped me. Here I was sending smoke signals to myself through message boxes and the debug window is perfect for clearing this issue up. I'll re-edit my post again once I've resolved it! Thanks for all your help David!

Comment: Keep those VB6 skills handy - it's the COBOL of the future (I'm remembering Y2K, when those guys were being brought out of retirement & paid small fortunes).

Comment: Thanks David. Your help set me back on track and your tip put a smile back on my face for the day. Kinda been grimacing at the sight of VB6 but every language and application can serve a purpose I suppose.

Comment: Glad to have helped!  Also ... well, everybody likes to put down VB6, but it's just so darned useful sometimes!  There are entire shops with immense codebases of VB6 who aren't even considering moving - it's just too huge a project.  Some day, those skills _will_ come in handy. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You specify `Details.func_ID) Like "Simp_*"`. In your data sample, there are no records with `Simp_` string in it

Comment: My apologies George. The sample mockup doesn't really coincide with what I've got coming out of Access.. I'll edit my post to reflect the actual data and statements I'm working with!